# ControllerFeatureProvider not filter controllers by name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, class-library, .net-5

I would like filter my controllers to remove Testing controllers in RELEASE mode in NET 5 preview.
Looks like everything working fine in the filter class (returns false for "TestingController"), but my controller is still available in RELEASE mode.

I use this filter class from a class library project:

```
public class TestingControllerFeatureProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider
{
    public TestingControllerFeatureProvider()
    {
    }

    protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        if (typeInfo != null && typeInfo.Name.ToLower().Contains("testing"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return base.IsController(typeInfo);
    }
}
```

and this code in startup.cs:

```
IMvcCoreBuilder MVC = services.AddMvcCore();

#if RELEASE
            MVC.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(m =>
            {
                m.FeatureProviders.Add(new TestingControllerFeatureProvider());
            });
#endif
```

What I'am doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: In what scenario do you need to delete the controller containing ‘testing’

Comment: @YiyiYou in debug mode I have helper controllers to manage testing methods with cypress tester in separate razor class libraries. I would like disable these controllers in release mode (in production).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use MiddleWare to do it.Firstly you can set a `UseTesting` in appsettings.json.
Here is a demo worked:

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "UseTesting": 1
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            if (Int32.Parse(Configuration["UseTesting"]).Equals(1)) {
                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
                    if (context.Request.Path.Value.ToString().Split("/")[1].Contains("Test"))
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                        return;
                    }
                    await next.Invoke();
                    // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
                });
            }
```

When in release mode,you can change UseTesting value to 1 in appsettings.json.

Result(I test when UseTesting=1 and UseTesting =0):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems very good, but I have two little problems: this code filters not only the controllers, but also every request (css files etc..). My second problem: if the variable is set to 0, I see an empty page instead of 404 page, looks like the middleware chain broken in my case with the "return" part.

Comment: Firstly,I test css file,and it will not be filtered by middleware.Secondly,I use `context.Response.StatusCode = 404;` before `return`,and then it will return a default 404 page.You can try a url not exists,it will return a page which is the same with I shown in the answer.

Comment: In my second test only the controller was filtered, I will test it deeply. But the empty page is still appear for me, instead of 404 page, what is the order of your middlewares?

Comment: Ok now its working with custom StatusCodePages and Error handling... thanks for help!

Comment: I already mark it with +1 point, but I wait a little for the suggestions to fix the original featurprovider code too.